# XSD: What's the difference between these two?

Tags: xsd

In the first one, I put the minOccurs and maxOccurs in the `sequence` element:

```
<xs:element name="Prerequisites" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Prerequisite" type="PrerequisiteType"/>              
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the second one, I put it in the contained `element` element:

```
  <xs:element name="Prerequisites" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Prerequisite" type="PrerequisiteType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>              
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case there is no difference, i.e. both definitions describe the same language.

What you define in first example is the limit of the occurrences of the whole sequence, in the second case only of one element of the sequence.

Comment: It is better practise not to use minOccurs and maxOccurs in xs:sequence. And I think more readable too.

Comment: I'd avoid using minOccurs/maxOccurs on sequence too, it could complicate processing.